# Excel: How to Switch Row/Column in Pivot Chart but not in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, charts, pivot

In Excel 2013 I have a pivot table and chart combo. The table is as it needs it be but the chart needs to swap the x and y axis as the series are in rows in the table.

When I select the pivot chart and click *PivotChart Tools | Design | Switch Row/Column* both the pivot chart and the pivot column swap.  This also happens if I right-click the pivot chart and select *Select Data | Switch Row/Column*.

How do I get the pivot chart to work with series in rows?  I need the pivot table and pivot chart to stay in sync as the pivot table filters are applied.